How do I group polynomials in list that are either negatives or multiples of each other? I want to group polynomials f and g, if f=(-1)^n g^m
Specifically, I have a list that looks like:
{(1-x),(-1+x),(x+y)^2, (-x-y)^3, (1-x)^3,... }
I want to partition this into smaller lists that look like:
{(1-x),(-1+x),(1-x)^3...}
{(x+y),(-x-y)^3,...}
etc...
i.e. 2 elements of my list, a and b, belong in the same group if a=(-1)^n b^m OR b=(-1)^n a^m, for some integers n and m,
Any help would be great. Thank you very much.

There's probably a simpler implementation, but something like this should work:
list = {(1 - x), (-1 + x), (x + y)^2, (-x - y)^3, (1 - x)^3};

Gather[list, 0 === PolynomialMod[#1, #2] || 0 === PolynomialMod[#2, #1] &]
(* {{1 - x, -1 + x, (1 - x)^3}, {(x + y)^2, (-x - y)^3}} *)

